# How to mock socket.io with Angular and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, jasmine, angular-mock

I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly mock Socket.io in an Angular application using Jasmine and Karma.

Here are the files found in `karma.conf.js`:

```
'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
'bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js',
'bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js',
'bower_components/angular-socket-io/mock/socket-io.js',
'public/javascripts/*.js',
'ng_tests/**/*.js',
'ng_tests/stateMock.js'
```

Here is how my controller looks:

```
var lunchrControllers = angular.module('lunchrControllers', []);

lunchrControllers.controller('UserMatchingController', ['$state', 'socket',
    function ($state, socket) {
        socket.emit('match');

        socket.on('matched', function (data) {
            $state.go('users.matched', {name: data.name})
        });
    }]);
```

Here is my socket factory:

```
var lunchrFactories = angular.module('lunchrFactories', []);

lunchrFactories.factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {
    return socketFactory();
});
```

Here is the main angular module:

```
var lunchrApp = angular.module('lunchr', ['ui.router', 'btford.socket-io', 'lunchrControllers', 'lunchrFactories' ]);

lunchrApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider.
            state('mainPage', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/partials/main.jade',
                controller: 'MainPageController'
            })
            .state('users', {
                url: '/users',
                templateUrl: '/partials/users.jade',
                controller: 'UserController'
            })
            .state('users.matching', {
                url: '/matching',
                templateUrl: '/partials/users.matching.jade',
                controller: 'UserMatchingController'
            })
            .state('users.matched', {
                url: '/matched',
                templateUrl: '/partials/users.matched.jade',
                params:{name:null},
                controller: 'UserMatchedController'
            })
            .state('register', {
                url:'/register',
                templateUrl: 'partials/register.jade',
                controller: 'RegisterController'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

Here is the test I'm having trouble figuring out:

```
'use strict';

describe('UserMatchingController', function () {
    beforeEach(module('lunchr'));
    beforeEach(module('stateMock'));


    var $controller, $rootScope, $state, socket;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

        $state = $injector.get('$state');

        // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
        $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

        socket = $injector('socket');
    }));

    afterEach(function () {
        $state.ensureAllTransitionsHappened();
    });

    function createController() {
        return $controller('UserMatchingController', {'$scope': $rootScope});
    }

    describe('on initiazation', function(){
        it('socket should emit a match', function() {
            createController();

            // would like to be able to expect a socket.emit call
        });
        it('should transition to users.matched upon receiving matched', function(){
            createController();
            $state.expectTransitionTo('user.matched');
            socket.receive('matched', {name: 'Ben'}); //This errors out with: cannot read property 'receive' of undefined
        })
    })
});
```

I suspect that `socket` isn't being properly injected and I'm not sure how to fix it. Similarly, I'd also like to be able to expect that a call to `socket.emit` is made but don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'd like to use [this socket mock](https://github.com/nullivex/angular-socket.io-mock) if possible but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the `sockMock` object defined in [this solution](https://github.com/hackify/hackify-server/blob/master/test/controllers.test.js).

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) to create a mock socket object.

For example, in your `beforeEach`, initialize socket to be an empty object:

```
socket = {};
```

`createController()` must pass the mock to the controller:

```
$controller('UserMatchingController', {'$scope': $rootScope, 'socket': socket});
```

Then in your test do something like this:

```
socket.emit = sinon.spy(); //Create a spy so we can check if it was called
createController();

expect(socket.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('match');
```

You will need the packages [sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon) and [jasmine-sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-sinon). Also if you are using Karma, it will need [karma-sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-sinon). You can find more guidelines on the setup on the respective pages.

EDIT: In your case your mock needs to have `on` and `emit` functions every time, as they are needed by the controller. In this case it might be better to put this into the `beforeEach` function:

```
socket = {
  emit : sinon.spy(),
  on : sinon.spy()
};
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Two questions: is there a reason you suggest using the ```spy``` function of Sinon vs that of Jasmine? Also, does the edit I've added affect your recommendation?

Comment: That mock you linked needs for you to create one of them, pass it as dependency to controller and then after test confirm the emits hash contains something. Personally I prefer using sinon. In this case I used a spy as only needed to know if a ton has been called. If you want it to call the callback (e.g. For the event), you should use `sinon.stub().callsArgWith(0, mockData) `. I actually have not used Jasmine's spies, either will work I guess.