# Mock Angularjs socket and test in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, sockets, unit-testing, websocket, jasmine

I have a [angularjs websocket](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket) working in a `service`. I want to test the basic `onOpen onClose onMessage and send` events of the `socket` using `jasmine`. Here is how the socket is defined in the `service`:

```
angular.module('srvSocket', [])
  .service('Socket', function($websocket, localConfig) {

var ws = $websocket('ws://'+localConfig.apiUrl);

ws.onMessage(onMessage);
ws.onError(onError);
ws.onClose(onClose);

ws.onOpen(function () {
      console.log('conn opened');
    });

function onMessage(data){
  console.log('data received');
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({test: 'hi'}));
}

 function onError(err) {
          console.log(err);
        };

 function onClose() {
          console.log('conn closed');
        };
  });
```

Here is how I am using (trying to) service in test:

```
describe('Service: Socket', function () {

  var socket, $websocket, $websocketBackend, lc;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ngWebSocket', 'ngWebSocketMock'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_Socket_, _$websocketBackend_, _$websocket_, localConfig){
    socket = _Socket_;
    lc = localConfig;
    $websocket = _$websocket_;
    $mockSocketBackend = _$websocketBackend_;
    $mockSocketBackend.mock();
  }));

 it('should connect to socket api', function(){
     var url = 'ws://'+config.apiUrl;
     $mockSocketBackend.expectConnect(url);
     ws = $websocket(url);
     expect($mockSocketBackend.isConnected(url)).to.be.above(0);
  });
});
```

This is how far I got following the [documentation here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket). What I am basically looking for is how to setup a mock websocket server for the service? That would enable me to test all my expectations on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would mock the entire `$websocket`, as shown in this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/qUrhzD6HpCsDze808QkE?p=preview%20plunk), this way you have complete control on what an how you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can use `sockMock` from [this solution](https://github.com/hackify/hackify-server/blob/master/test/controllers.test.js) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846048/how-to-mock-socket-io-with-angular-and-jasmine)

I hope this helps